cambio de apariencia en textformfield
necesito de su ayuda.
Estoy trabado con ese cambio de apariencia cuando la validacion del campo es erronea.
He intentado agregando errorFocusBorder y errorBorder pero no lo puedo resolver. Estoy utilizando ValidationBuilder. Cuando se produce el error ya sea por longitud, vacio o tipo de dato se genera ese error en el que se "achica" el TextFormField. Hay alguna forma de evitarlo o "desactivar ese texto de El campo es obligatorio" y no se muestre ?Muchas gracias!!
este es mi codigo de textformfield y customcontainer:
import 'package:changapp/shared/custom_container_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String? Function(String?)? validation;
  final String hintText;
  final Icon? icon;
  final String? fieldName;
  final bool obscureText;
  const TextFieldWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.hintText,
    this.icon,
    this.validation,
    this.fieldName,
    this.obscureText = false,
    required this.controller,
  });
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomContainer(
      width: 320,
      height: 40,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        // onTap: () {
        //   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
        // },
        validator: validation,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: icon,
          hintText: hintText,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double? width;
  final double? height;

  const CustomContainer({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
    this.width,
    this.height,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: const [BoxShadow(blurRadius: 3.5, color: Colors.grey)],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}


En el InputDecoration coloca:
errorText: null 

Asi no mostrará el mensaje de la validación
o tambien puedes colocar una condicionante para darte una idea
errorText: validation.isEmpty ? null : validation

espero y te ayude
  TextFormField(
    controller: controller,
    obscureText: obscureText,
    // onTap: () {
    //   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
    // },
    validator: validation,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      prefixIcon: icon,
      hintText: hintText,
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      errorText: null
    ),
  ),

